# Vulnerabilidades Angular

Tags: angular, npm

En mi proyecto de Angular/cli me ha aparecido lo siguiente:

```
=== npm audit security report ===                        


                             Manual Review                                  
         Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             
                                                                            
      Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance           


      Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service                          

      Package         postcss                                                       

      Patched in      >=8.2.10                                                      

      Dependency of   @angular-devkit/build-angular [dev]                           

      Path            @angular-devkit/build-angular > resolve-url-loader > postcss  

      More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693                             


      High            Memory Exposure                                               

      Package         dns-packet                                                    

      Patched in      >=5.2.2                                                       


      Path            @angular-devkit/build-angular > webpack-dev-server > bonjour  
                      > multicast-dns > dns-packet                                  

      More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1745
```

He hecho npm audit fix y npm audit fix --force, pero no me lo soluciona, entrando en la página de información me dice que tengo que actualizar las dependencias, pero cómo se hace eso?

Comment: Solo vuelve a instalarlas,  por ejemplo si tienes dotenv pones `npm i dotenv'

Comment: Eso ya lo he probado y no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Eso significa que la versión de build-angular que seguro tienes definida en tu archivo `package.json` tiene como consecuencia el usar esas versiones de esas dependencias.

npm va a resolver siempre lo que debe instalar a partir de tu `package.json` y tratará de resolver diferencias entre paquetes, buscando instalar la versión que se ajuste a todos los requerimientos. Por ejemplo, build_angular en la versión que lo tengas pedirá una versión o rango de versiones de angular/core (depende de cada paquete, dirán >=8.0.0 o algo similar). Lo puedes ver en el package.json de cada uno, en tu `/node_modules`

Ahí audit no te puede ayudar porque posiblemente no hay forma de satisfacer tus dependencias y actualizar eso. Necesitas, pues, revisar si puedes actualizar la versión de tus dependencias y ver que no entren en conflicto con la versión de Angular sobre la que estás trabajando (y la versión de nodejs / npm que estés usando, que eso es otro infierno)